# Can you freeze caramel sauce?

Tags: sauce, freezing, caramel

As caramel sauce makes everything better from cakes to brownies, cookies even enhances the flavor of popcorn. I am thinking to make caramel sauce and freeze it, so it can be used as and when required. So can caramel sauce be 
frozen? How long does caramel sauce last in the fridge?

Comment: In the title you say freeze, in the body you say refrigerate. Which are you asking about?

Comment: Edited question

Comment: Caramel sauce being mostly sugar, which resists spoilage, I'm guessing will last for a very long time just in the fridge. And since it's like two bucks of ingredients if you're using butter and 20 minutes for a large batch that lasts several months, I'd personally just make what I guess I can use, if it goes bad on me toss it, make less next time.

Comment: You can also make toasted sugar / dry caramel, which should likely last for as long as you'll need it to in a sealed container: https://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2016/05/dry-toasted-sugar-granulated-caramel-recipe.html

It is however a lot more time and bother than regular caramel.